# Http 404 error with Java Tomcat8.5 Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat8, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have following the setting on the website to config Javaweb with Maven run on IntelliJ idea, anything seem like be ok but when i hit run/debug button to run my project, the Output screen that Tomcat is started, but the web page started at http://localhost:8080/ shows an 404 error.

[image]

If I use Tomcat Plugins to run my project (tomcat7:run) it is work fine,

[image]

***more details as below:***

**Edit Configuration:**

[image]

**Modules Setting**:

[image]

**Artifacts setting**:

[image]

**Facets setting**:

[image]

**web.xml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Project Structure** :

[image]

I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. thanks so much! And i will upload more details if needed.

Comment: add your project name after localhost:8080 it will show your project index page 
or rename your war file name as ROOT.war and deploy to tomcat then it will work as localhost:8080

Comment: useless,it’s still show 404 with Message /day54_Maven(my project name)

Comment: after I deploy war file to tomcat it was work. but i want to know the reason if I make a little change on my code, should i need re-deploy to tomcat again. it is not final solution right？thanks so much.

Comment: 1. Yes when you made changes in java file then you need to re-deploy WAR file 

2. you just made changes in static content like JSP, CSS or javascript then you dont need to re deploy war file

Comment: OK I see thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/manager"  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

**set path to your web app path**